# css a:hover not applying in Safari

Tags: html, css, http

the css code posted below seems to work fine in internet explorer and google chrome but when in safari the `a:hover` effect seems to only apply when i right click the element or when I go into inspect elements and click `hover` from the options for that `a` tag in the right sidebar. I believe that this problem may be due to http headers as I can see no problem in the source code. The url in question is available [here](https://howtohidefromnsa.com/static/css/test.html)

and the css code in question is:

```
#swag a:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

and the html is the following:

```
<p>Mouse over and click the link: 
    <div id="swag">
        <a href="http://www.example.com">example.com</a>
    </div>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you try putting `!important` next to the CSS style?  ... `color: black !important;`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i just tried that and it is not making a difference.

Comment: Please inspect the anchor element and make sure your hover rule is there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have and the hover rule is there, when I right click over the link the hover rule is a applied and the font turns black, which indicates to me that the rule must be applying.

Comment: Is this on a touch device?

Comment: @torazaburo no this is safari on OS X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full reboot of my macbook has solved my issue. The nature of the issue is  still unknown to me.